# Tensorflow could not detect my GPU GTX 1050 Ti

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

Tensorflow is not detecting my GPU
I have a laptop with Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti GPU. I followed tensorflow documentation: [text](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source). I have Python 3.8.1, Tensorflow 2.3, CUDA 10.1, and CUDNN 7.6.

when I run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num of GPU Available", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

it keeps printing:
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Num of GPU Available 0

is there any solution?

Comment: Hi @Nada Sliem, Could you please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) and verify that you have followed all the mentioned step by step instructions and set the path for the software correctly. Let us know if the issue still persists.